# Stuck in grub rescue after trying to uninstall ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, uninstall, windows-10

I have/(had) Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 on my HP ProBook 440 G4.
I wanted to uninstall the Ubuntu following [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Rq4zovHiWk).
The current problem is when I boot the machine I'm getting into *grub rescue*.
The problem was caused by the following steps:

- I had two partitions for Ubuntu (the second one was a swap partition suppose). In the Windows *disk management* I deleted the first volume. Then, when I wanted to delete the second one (the swap partition), it told me the *disk is in use* and I **didn't** proceed. Then I wanted to allocate the space from the first partition and it failed as it told me *there is not enough space*.
- I restarted the windows while holding `shift`, the windows troubleshooting opened (or something like this) and I proceeded to the command line as recommended in the instructions. But instead of the windows command line the *grub rescue* opened with the error: *unknown file system*
- I didn't figure out what should I do and after pressing `Ctrl+Alt+Del` I could boot into the *Windows recovery drive* which I have on a USB. As instructed [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/#:%7E:text=Just%20boot%20into%20Windows%20and,loader%20entry%20from%20your%20computer.) I proceeded to the command line and entered `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`. But after restarting I still boot into the grub. I also tried the next command `bootrec.exe /fixboot` which was in the first instruction, but I got an error *access denied*.
- I have two types of backups for my system. The one is with Acronis. But I cannot boot into the Acronis recovery media. The second is the standard windows, I didn't try it yet.

I appreciate your help very much!

updated:
[screenshot of acronis recovery tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxymB.jpg)

UPDATE (23.06.2020): Eventually, I managed to restore the system with Acronis. But I am a bit curious because I tried to restore the system to the state which was before I started to delete Ubuntu. But now Windows is Ok but with Ubuntu is something different:
I can boot directly into Windows without Ubuntu loader. The partitions for Ubuntu seem to empty: [disk management overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf48q.png)
But when I'm in Acronis Rescue Media it shows something different:
[linux swap partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0CoR.jpg) (BTW: what is `linux swap partition`?)
So how can I check if Ubuntu is gone or not?

I am going to clone Windows to another SSD and reformat the old one. Should there be any issues with this because of Ubuntu?

UPDATE (24-06-2020): The disk where both OS resides is in *GPT partition style*. The BIOS mode is UEFI.

- I can directly boot into windows. How can I check if I have any left-over of the ubuntu loader?
- Can I just format/delete the partitions where ubuntu is/was from windows *disk management*?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can maybe post a screenshot of your disk partitions, if you can boot into Windows or you can try with Ubuntu Live->Disks  make a screenshot and edit your question.. If you plan to install 20.04 LTS then try to delete the Ubuntu partitions, boot with Ubuntu Live 20.04 and install using the option Something Else (with 4 partitions) and after done reboot you should get the grub menu...

Comment: Does [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) help you to bring back your windows bootloader ?

Comment: Your instructions look like they are for a BIOS install. Is your Windows UEFI/gpt or BIOS/MBR? If UEFI, you can directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f12, check your manual. If UEFI: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: Check if your hard drive is MBR or GPT. If it is MBR, maybe there's still Ubuntu MBR on the disk. You'll need to rebuild the MBR so it can boot Windows.